# Interesting R error related to calling functions

Tags: r, plot

I have a function that I made and it goes as follows:

```
plot_colorByDensity = function(x,y,
                               ylim=c(min(y),max(y)),
                               xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),
                               xlab="",ylab="",main="") {
    #print(xlim)
    x1 = x
    x2 = y
    df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
    x <- densCols(x1,x2, colramp=colorRampPalette(c("black", "white")))
    df$dens <- col2rgb(x)[1,] + 1L
    cols <-  colorRampPalette(c("#000099", "#00FEFF", "#45FE4F","#FCFF00", "#FF9400", "#FF3100"))(256)
    df$col <- cols[df$dens]
    plot(x2~x1, data=df[order(df$dens),], 
         ylim=ylim,xlim=xlim,pch=20,col=col,
         cex=2,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,
         main=main)
}
```

It produces a plot where color represents density of points. Take a look at this output, and the error that the function above produces, leading to no plot being drawn:

```
> x
 [1]  0.4855447 -0.7463454 -0.3623149  0.4508110 -0.6204866 -0.8302512  1.7498530
 [8]  0.9920785  0.5215649  1.0366535
> y
 [1]  0.4855447 -0.7463454 -0.3623149  0.4508110 -0.6204866 -0.8302512  1.7498530
 [8]  0.9920785  0.5215649  1.0366535
> plot_colorByDensity(x,y)
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

**Here's the interesting part: When I uncomment that `print(xlim)` line in the function, I don't get this error and it plots fine.**

What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, R [doesn't immediately evaluate the arguments](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation), so, in your case,  when evaluation of your function starts, `xlim` does not actually contain a vector with the minimum and maximum values in `x` because the expression to generate those values hasn't been evaluated yet. Without the call to `print`, the expression isn't evaluated until you get to `plot`. But by that time, `x` has taken on a new value:

```
x <- densCols(x1,x2, colramp=colorRampPalette(c("black", "white")))
```

The best way to see this is to move your call to `print` to the line after the assignment of `x`:

```
x <- densCols(x1,x2, colramp=colorRampPalette(c("black", "white")))
print(xlim)
```

You'll see this:

```
[1] "#000000" "#FFFFFF"
```

which is clearly an invalid `xlim`.

The easiest way to fix this is simply to pick a new name for `x`. (You *could* also force evaluation of `xlim` at the beginning of the function by calling `force(xlim)`.)